# Spring Boot, Spring Security and Thymeleaf: Apply CsrfFilter to website with form

Tags: spring-security, csrf, thymeleaf

I'm using Spring Security with Thymeleaf and want to create a login and a register form on different sites that make both use of CSRF protection. Protecting the login site is easy, as with the folloing WebSecurity configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
```

Spring supports adding CSRF protection in general by the Security Filter Chain that is build in the configure method. This Filter Chain contains a CSRFFilter that adds/evaluates the CSRF token. This Filter Chain is then used for all matches defined in the above configuration. The mechanism of getting the Filters that are applied to a request can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.java) in the method

`doFilterInternal(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)`

The problem is, if I add the "/register" site to this configuration, the user is redirected to the "/login" site first. If I don't add it to the above config, the mentioned FilterChain is not applied (and so not the CsrfFilter).

So what I want is to reuse the CsrfFilter in the Filter Chain of the "/register" site, but I don't know how to do that.

I'd prefer this approach to other ideas like writing a custom CSRF filter as suggested [here](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2012/04/csrf-defense-in-spring-mvc-31.html) or [here](http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-1-stateless-csrf-protection/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the Spring Security Filter chain is applied to all endpoints mentioned in the list provided to requestMatchers().antMatchers().

So to use CSRF protection for a site that is not the login site, I just had to add it to this list and then permit all access to it, so there is no redirect to the login page. My final config looks like this

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers()
            // consider these patterns for this config and the Security Filter Chain
            .antMatchers("/login", "/register", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access", "/oauth/token_key",
                    "/oauth/check_token", "/oauth/error")
            .and()
            // define authorization behaviour
            .authorizeRequests()
            // /register is allowed by anyone
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            // /oauth/authorize needs authentication; enables redirect to /login
            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
            // any other request in the patterns above are forbidden
            .anyRequest().denyAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            // we have a custom login page at /login
            // that is permitted to everyone
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From all of this i understood the problem is that you want people to access /register without needing to login first. Which is a simple fix:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .requestMatchers()
// add this line
.antMatchers("/register").permitAll().and

//
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
}
```

Comment: Hi Aeseir! That's not the problem. My aim is to enable CSRF protection in my /register form. Spring supports adding CSRF protection in general by the Security Filter Chain that is build in the configure method. This Filter Chain contains a CSRFFilter that add/evaluates the CSRF token. If I add the /register site the way you suggested the site will be ignored by the Filter Chain and therefore, CSRF protection will not be used. The links I added to my post suggest ways to add a manual CSRF protection mechanism, but I'd rather re-use the existing one by Spring.

Comment: I must have misunderstood. So you creating a custom security filter chain instead of using the existing one and hence the issue?